# Why is prototype not inherited?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsley.js

Could you explain why Validator.js starts the way it does(see first code snippet) and why I'm not able to call the prototyped method validate (second snippet)

I'm currently playing with validator.js ([github/validator.js](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/validator.js/blob/master/src/validator.js))

the code begins like this:

```
    ( function ( exports ) {

var Validator = function ( options ) {
this.__class__ = 'Validator';
this.__version__ = '@@version';
this.options = options || {};
this.bindingKey = this.options.bindingKey || '_validatorjsConstraint';

return this;
};

Validator.prototype = {

constructor: Validator,

validate: function ( objectOrString, AssertsOrConstraintOrGroup, group ) {
  if ( 'string' !== typeof objectOrString && 'object' !== typeof objectOrString )
    throw new Error( 'You must validate an object or a string' );
......
```

Yet I'm NOT ABLE to call the validate method in my node.js code which is as follows:

```
var Validator = require('./static/vendor/parsley/validator.js'),
Assert = Validator.Assert,
Constraint = Validator.Constraint;

Validator.Validator().validate( 'foo', new Assert().Length( { min: 4 } ) );
```

Thank you,
Baradi

Comment: Please include your `exports` line where you export your `Validator` class from your module, and provide an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an instance (that will inherit from the prototype), you will need to use the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
new Validator.Validator().validate( 'foo', new Assert().Length( { min: 4 } ) );
```

Also, from a constructor you don't need to `return this`. That would've hinted at the mistake as well.

Comment: @Baradi, to make it easier to read: var v = new Validator.Validator(); v.validate(...);

Comment: Thanks, this worked, although with parenthesis like this: (new Validator.Validator()).validate( 'foo', new Assert().Length( { min: 4 } ) );

Comment: Really? It should work without them as well. Of course, grouping or a instance variable make it more clear.

Comment: maybe I should remove this Validator class encapsulated in Validator object... It may be confusing, and having 5-6 static methods like validate would make the job I think..

Comment: If it's good to be used as a singleton, yes, but if those `options` can differ then a class with instances might not be a bad idea. And you might rename the module to `Validation`, to remove that duplication.